# Scipy Optimize returns initial guess as solution

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, scipy

I am trying to find the optimal lower and upper bound to filter my dataframe. I am trying to minimize the absolute value of the mean of the target column. The function works as intended, but when scipy.optimize cannot optimize.

```
h = 3.04
a = 2.56
d = 3.25
nv_h = 1/h / (1/h+1/a+1/d)

h_l = 0.1
h_u = 0.9

dict = df.to_dict('records')

def fil(x):
    h_l, h_u = x
    for row in dict:
        if h_l < row['nv Hwp'] < h_u:
            row['HW2'] = row['HW']
            row['h_error'] = row['HW2'] - nv_h
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
    return abs(df.h_error.mean())

bnds = ((0, None), (0, None))
result = optimize.minimize(fil, x0=(0, 1), bounds=bnds, options={'disp': True})
print(result.message)
print(result.x)
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.